# Prolog: replace the nth item in the list with the first

Tags: list, prolog

I'd like to have a Prolog predicate that can replace the nth item in the list with the first.

Example:

```
% replace(+List,+Counter,-New List, %-First Item).
?- replace([1,2,3,4,5],3,L,Z).

L = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5]
Z = 1
```

I don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the predicate `nth1(Index, List, Item, Rest)`:

```
?- nth1(3, [1,2,3,4,5], Item, Rest).
Item = 3,
Rest = [1, 2, 4, 5].

?- nth1(3, List, 1, [1,2,4,5]).
List = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5].
```

Putting it all together:

```
replace(List, Index, NewList, First) :-
    List = [First|_],
    nth1(Index, List, _Removed, Rest),
    nth1(Index, NewList, First, Rest).
```

Examples:

```
?- replace([1,2,3,4,5], 3, L, Z).
L = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5],
Z = 1.

?- replace([one,two,three,four,five], 4, NewList, First).
NewList = [one, two, three, one, five],
First = one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, slightly faster (replacing succ/2 with simple arithmetic helped performance):

```
replace_nth_with_first(Nth1, Lst, LstReplaced, First) :-
    must_be(positive_integer, Nth1),
    Lst = [First|_Tail],
    replace_nth_with_first_(Nth1, Lst, LstReplaced, First).

% Keeping the arguments simple, to ensure that Nth1 = 1 matches
replace_nth_with_first_(1, Lst, LstReplaced, First) :-
    !,
    Lst = [_Head|Tail],
    LstReplaced = [First|Tail].
replace_nth_with_first_(Nth1, [H|Lst], [H|LstReplaced], First) :-
    Nth is Nth1 - 1,
    replace_nth_with_first_(Nth, Lst, LstReplaced, First).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- replace_nth_with_first(3, [a, b, c, d, e], R, F).
R = [a,b,a,d,e],
F = a.
```

Performance comparison:

```
?- numlist(1, 2000000, L), time(replace_nth_with_first(1000000, L, R, First)).
% 1,000,004 inferences, 0.087 CPU in 0.087 seconds (100% CPU, 11428922 Lips)

% slago's
?- numlist(1, 2000000, L), time(replace_f(L, 1000000, R, First)).
% 2,000,011 inferences, 0.174 CPU in 0.174 seconds (100% CPU, 11484078 Lips)
```

Note the argument order, as per https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/split-list/4836/8

Comment: A faster code is: `rnwf(N, [F|R], L, F) :- rnwf_(N, [F|R], L, F). rnwf_(1, [_|R], [F|R], F) :- !. rnwf_(N, [H|R], [H|L], F) :- M is N-1, rnwf_(M, R, L, F).`

Comment: That is because `succ(Nth, Nth1)` is slower than `Nth is Nth1 - 1` :-)

Comment: Yes, it is! Because it requires both arguments to be natural numbers (it must check this condition) and also needs to work properly in three different modes `(-,+)`, `(+,-)`, `(+,+)`.

Comment: "*attempting to be faster than slago's*" - I tried `length(Start, Index), append(Start, X, List)` to slice off the start and end in two big chunks, then recombine them. It's a lot worse; from the amount of inferences added I think making the intermediate lists is real copying, not lightweight start/end references into the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `append/3`. Nice, concise, and declarative:

```
replace( [X|Xs] , 1 , [X|Xs], X ) .  % replacing the first item in the list is a no-op
replace( Ls     , I , L1    , X ) :- % for anything else...
  I > 1 ,                            % - the index must be greater than 1
  J is I-1 ,                         % - the length of the prefix is I-1
  length( [X|Xs], J ) ,              % - construct an empty/unbound prefix list of the desired length
  append( [X|Xs] , [_|Ys] , Ls ) ,   % - break the source list up into the desired bits
  append( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] , L1 )     % - and then put everything back together in the desired manner
  .                                  % Easy!
```